# Airport transit in KUL and DXB with 4 months on passport?

Tags: transit, passports, kul, dxb

I am an Indonesian living in Germany. I will be traveling to Indonesia via Dubai and Kuala Lumpur. From Kuala Lumpur I will take a different airline. I just noticed that some countries ask for a 6 months passport validity to be able to enter the country. Does it also affect people who just stay a couple of hours for airport transfer? My passport expires in 4 months. Would it be a trouble if I don't renew it before traveling?

Comment: Which airlines are you flying?  Are the two airlines booked as one ticket, or separate tickets?

Comment: I booked it as separate tickets; Emirates and AirAsia.

Comment: It is possible that your embassy in Germany can extend the validity of your passport by a few months. You should see if that is an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Emirates and Air Asia uses separate terminals at KLIA, you will be required to pass through Malaysian Immigration, and [Timatic](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/MY-Malaysia-passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm) states:

> Malaysia (MY)
>
> Passport required.
>   - Passport and/or passport replacing travel documents must be valid at least six months on date of arrival.

So yes, I would recommend you renew your passport first if at all possible.

That said, since you have an immediate onward connection you *might* be able to argue a) Emirates into them into letting you on board (this would usually entail signing a disclaimer where you agree to all responsibility if you're not allowed in) and b) Malaysia into letting you into the country.  But why risk it?

Comment: So, if my second flight is from the same terminal, I may be able to go through since I will not have to pass the immigration control?
I just noticed that there's this requirement with minimum passport validity and I have already booked everything (trains and flights), thinking it would be no problem since I'm going home anyway and wanted to renew my passport there *sigh*

Comment: Yes.  However, all Air Asia flights use the LCCT and they don't have any transfer facilities (unless you're connecting from Air Asia), so unless you change airlines, you will have to go through immigration.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I hope the new passport will be finished by then.

Answer (score -2):

Since you are not going through the customs and not leaving the Airport you are considered as in an International zone, then I don't think it would be a problem as long as your final destination doesn't requires it.

Comment: I will be traveling with two different airlines. The first airline flies to Kuala Lumpur (they require 6 months validity). Do you think it would be okay? I will stay 3 hours then continue fly to Indonesia. I am currently in the process of renewing my passport, but I'm not sure if it will be finished on time. I would like to avoid changing the whole itinerary.

Comment: Then you will have to go through the customs and that could be a problem.try to search for the company's policy, but indeed it will be better for you to have your new passeport before leaving. sorry i can't tell you more than this.

Comment: If you're not sure, it's best not to provide an answer.  Uncertainty can be incorrect. If you have actual experience doing this, or if you have a source (eg website of airlines/airports/embassies stating the requirements) then it's a very useful thing to put in an answer, but given your comment already contradicts your answer, it's potentially more dangerous than useful if wrong.

Comment: Duely noted, sorry about that, I'll try to find useful informations in order to help printemps. Thanks for pointing that out.